# unfamiliar notch filter configuration

Tags: operational-amplifier, filter, frequency, active-filter, cutoff-frequency

[image]

This is a configuration of the notch filter that I saw in some design. It is very different from the Active Twin-T notch filter configs that show up on a quick google search. Any idea what is going on in this design?

Also this seems to be a 60 Hz notch, I'm struggling to get this to be a 50 Hz notch, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Freq related components include the caps, resistors, and that sine generator(that is the input?).  What point is the output you wish to affect?

Comment: Consider U2 is a kind of gyrator configuration: what does its input impedance (looking in along the C1 path) look like? You will find your answer there.

Comment: In the future, please label important nets. What net is V(n003)?

Comment: I've closed this question because of it being a subset of the typical graphic equalizer gyrator circuit linked to in the close message. I guess this might be seen as harsh given that the OP would probably not have had the right search words to find it but, sorry if it comes across that way.

Comment: @Andyaka I see but it may be useful to beginners like me that come across such a configuration. It's like you mentioned, I had no idea about a gyrator circuit, but at first glance I was also unable to see the relevance in the question on the close message. It's the visual aspect that differs.

Comment: @TimWilliams i don't see what I can make out, can you please help me out there

Comment: @Andyaka The link to the graphic equalizer really didn't answer the question until Circuit Fantasist posted a recent answer. The answer I give below gives design equations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one of those interesting circuits.

The upper amplfier, U1, is a differential amplifier. When redrawn, as below, the differential amplifier topology becomes clear.

The Lower amplfier, U2, is a gyrator which forms an RLC equivalent circuit. This takes place of the differential amplifier's resistor from the non-inverting input to common.

The following equations refer to the reference designators in the schematic below.

$$ R = R_4 = R_5 $$
$$ G = {V_{out} \over V_{in}} = {j2 \pi C_2R^2(f^2-f_o^2) \over f(R+R_3)+j2\pi C_2R^2(f^2-f_o^2)} $$
$$f_o = {1 \over 2 \pi R \sqrt{C_1C_2}}$$
$$Q = {{\pi f_oC_2R} \over 2}$$
These conditions must be met:
$${R_1 \over R_2} = {R_3 \over R_4 + R_5} = {R_3 \over 2R}$$
These equations are from "Handbook of Operational Amplifer Circuit Design", by Stout (ISBN 0-07-061797-X), pg 13-1.

An example of the circuit with a notch around 50 Hz.

[image] 
Opamps are LTspice *UniversalOpAmp* with GBW=1Meg.

Comment: is a gyrator and  negative impedance converter the same thing?

Comment: why would someone go for this circuit than a classic notch circuit?

Comment: @Roshan Graphic equalizers is a common use since it uses few parts. It's also a ingenious configuration. Other things to look out for is noise performance. I don't know how this performs versus the T-notch filter. Other gyrator configurations for bandpass filters have better noise performance than many active filters.